# React - Call Parent function from OUTSIDE of Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I want to have the child component file from outside the class function

function saveSurveyData(survey) needs to call Parent function **handleTabs**()

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props);       
            this.handleTabs = this.handleTabs.bind(this);
        }

         handleTabs = () => {
            console.log('expecting call from Child component - function 
         }


         render() {   
            return (
                <Tab eventKey={1} title="child">
                    <Child handleTabs={this.handleTabs} />
                </Tab> 

            )
        }
    }

// Child Component

import React from 'react';
    import * as Survey from "survey-react";

    var surveyValueChanged = function (sender, options) {
        saveSurveyData(survey);
    };
    // critical surveyjs function
    function saveSurveyData(survey) {
        var data = survey.data;

        //need to call handleTabs() (parent) in this function which is outside of Child Component Class
        //handleTabs={this.handleTabs}
        this.handleTabs();  // HOW ?
    }

    class Child extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);

        }

        render()
            {
                return(
                    <Survey.Survey model={survey}
                        onValueChanged={surveyValueChanged} />
                )
            }
                }
```

I had been trying ref, props and state -  I just don't understand how to do this outside of child component.

Comment: If `handleTabs` just has generic Javascript functionality, you can move it outside the component. If it has React-specific functionality (like calling `setState`) then you'll have to pass it from the child to the function, and keep passing it along, i.e. something like this: `onValueChanged={(sender, options) => surveyValueChanged(sender, options, this.props.handleTabs)}` and so on until it gets to where it needs

Comment: handleTabs does indeed have (needs) setState  -   but hold on,  it looks like your saying that  this.props.handleTabs  would be set in the child ...  but then how do i pass down from parent  -   can you show me with an answer /example   thx

Comment: `surveyValueChanged` is build into a surveyjs code, and it is outside of class component - so the  this.props...   it doesn't like at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handleTab is passed to this.props. You should place surveyValueChanged and saveSurveyData to child component.

example:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);       
        this.handleTabs = this.handleTabs.bind(this);
    }

     handleTabs = () => {
        console.log('expecting call from Child component - function 
     }


     render() {   
        return (
            <Tab eventKey={1} title="child">
                <Child handleTabs={this.handleTabs} />
            </Tab> 

        )
    }
}

/// 
// Child
import React from 'react';
import * as Survey from "survey-react";



class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }

    surveyValueChanged = (sender, options) => {
       this.saveSurveyData(survey);
    };
    // critical surveyjs function
    saveSurveyData = (survey) => {
       var data = survey.data;       
       this.props.handleTabs();
    }

    render()
        {
            return(
                <Survey.Survey model={survey}
                    onValueChanged={this.surveyValueChanged} />
            )
        }

}
```

Comment: but you moved the functions - I know that seems harmless , but surveyValueChanged is not defined - I don't even know all the ramifications of moving SurveyJS functions into React is going to really work.

Comment: you should define function same a above (use arrow function) or bind this in constructor.

Comment: Well, I reluctantly moved a bunch of surveyjs functions inside the class component.  It is working now.   I thought I had issues in the past  - but it seems to be fine.  -  thx   ,   i still wonder how i could get access as some type of javascript prototype .... something should be able to

Answer (score 1):

```
<Child keyName={this.handleTabs} />
```

In the parent component you are passing this as a props (handleTabs is a method in parent)
Now to access any props value in Child component you can directly use (I habve changed the key name so that you can have clear concept)

//you want to use handleTabs (Since it is class based component use this keyword)

> this.props.KeyName();

Also you dont need to bind handle tab in parent component as you have created an arrow function which doesn't required bindings.
For normal functions you need to bind this.(So bind your child function)

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as Survey from "survey-react";

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.saveSurveyData = this.saveSurveyData.bind(this);
        this.surveyValueChanged = this.surveyValueChanged.bind(this);
    }
surveyValueChanged(sender, options) {
    this.saveSurveyData(survey);
};

 saveSurveyData(survey) {
    var data = survey.data;
    this.props.handleTabs(); 
    console.log(this.props.handleTabs()) 
}



    render()
        {
            return(
                <Survey.Survey model={survey}
                    onValueChanged={this.surveyValueChanged} />
            )
        }
            }
```

Comment: I don't understand this.    -  I need to call the parent `handleTabs` from outside the Child component class   -   what is  keyName and  then  KeyName()     props are not defined outside the class component ...

Comment: @JeremyMiller see I wanted to tell that whatever the keyName you are giving in parent , you can access from that name in child.

Comment: How?   sure i know i can access inside the child class component , but the Title I have says "OUTSIDE" ....  thus you can't get access to react props as I have have tested